# Wanting to stop setInterval using clearInterval, but to no avail

Tags: javascript, jquery, clearinterval

What I have is an element that have been linked with a keydown event.

The answer in similar questions all pointed to clearInterval, which I can't get to work.

First of all, I am using keyup events to check which arrow key is being pressed:

```
var counter = 0;

var yPosArray = [];
var right = true;
var done = false;
var leftX;
var rightX;
$(document).keydown (function(e) 
{
    rightX = parseInt(($('#movingObject').css('left')).replace('px','')) + 50;
    leftX = parseInt(($('#movingObject').css('left')).replace('px',''));

    if(e.which == 39)// right
    {
        $('#movingObject').find('img').attr('src','assets/images/mario_right.png');
        right = true;
        $('#xRight').val(rightX);
        $('#xLeft').val(leftX);
        move();
    }
    if(e.which == 37)   //left  
    {
        $('#movingObject').find('img').attr('src','assets/images/mario_left.png');
        right = false;
        $('#xRight').val(rightX);
        $('#xLeft').val(leftX);
        move();
    }
    if(e.which == 38)   //up    
    {
        if($('#movingObject').css('bottom') == '0px' && !false)
        {
            done = true;
            gravity();
            done = false;
        }
    }
});
```

As seen above, when this condition, `e.which == 37`, is met, the method `move()` is called. What the move method does, as seen below is to increase the element's `left` style attribute. The reason I have a timer, is so that the speed increases as the time goes by, but when the key is released, the event should stop firing. Because of this, I want to call the keyup event as seen in my last code snippet. Explanation will continue there.

```
var speed = 0;
var maxspeed = 0;
var timer;
function move()
{   
     var counter = 0;
     timer = setInterval(function () 
     {
         maxspeed++;
         $('#movingObject').css('left', moveX + maxspeed + 'px');
         ++counter;
    }, 70);
}
```

As seen above, the timer variable was declared before the `move` function was created, where it was set to the `setInterval` method. Because the variable is on the root level, if that makes sense, it can be used in all functions.

As seen below, I have initiated the keyup event to check for the different keys.

```
$(document).keyup (function(e) 
{
    var posX = parseInt(($('#movingObject').css('left')).replace('px',''));
    if(e.which == 39)// right
    {
        maxspeed = 0;
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }
    if(e.which == 37)   //left  
    {
        maxspeed = 0;
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }
    $('#movingObject').css('left', posX + 'px');
});
```

Above, I used clearInterval and tried setting `timer` equal to 0,after which it continues to increase.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MehLU/2/) with all my script for the stucture of my code.

**Any ideas why this is happening?**

Comment: You'll have to show how your two code snippets join up. In particular, your code should work provided the second snippet is within the same scope as `var timer` or a scope nested under it. If it's in a peer or ancestor scope, it won't work because `timer` won't be defined. (It would also be see how `move` gets called.)

Comment: Question has been updated with fiddle

Comment: You probably need something like a closure to scope timer to the inner functions you're apply to keyup etc.

Comment: *Why* do you set `timer` to `0`? It's meaningless after you've used the value.

Comment: I was just trying different methods to remove the timer event, but have not yet removed the code

Comment: @Bergi: It's a common pattern for knowing that the timer isn't running. (Granted the value's not being used here...)

Comment: @Phillip-juan: Fiddles are great, but they're off-site. Always post all of the relevant code (in context) **in** the question itself (and also include a fiddle if you like). Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I have added all relevant code to my question. thanks

Comment: @Phillip-juan: Good deal, but again, make it clear what the relationship between the code snippets is. (Is this really that hard?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time the `setInterval` will create a new `timer`,so when you `clearInterval` you have to clear all the timer(maybe some of them) you created.See this blow:

```
var speed = 0;
var maxspeed = 0;
var timer=[];
function move()
{   
     var counter = 0;
     timer.push(setInterval(function () 
     {
         maxspeed++;
         $('#movingObject').css('left', moveX + maxspeed + 'px');
         ++counter;
    }, 70));
}

$(document).keyup (function(e) 
{
    var posX = parseInt(($('#movingObject').css('left')).replace('px',''));
    if(e.which == 39)// right
    {
        maxspeed = 0;
        $.each(timer,function(i,n){
            clearInterval(n);
        });
        timer=[];
    }
    if(e.which == 37)   //left  
    {
        maxspeed = 0;
        $.each(timer,function(i,n){
            clearInterval(n);
        });
        timer=[];
    }
    $('#movingObject').css('left', posX + 'px');
});
```

Comment: Ouch! You should not iterate the whole `timer` array each time, but *remove* the cleared interval ids as well.

Comment: Yes you are right,I ignore it,it's better to pop the timer which is cleared.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when a user presses two (or more) keys at the same time. Then you will call `move()` subsequently without a keyup in between that clears the an interval - which means you're overwriting the `timer` interval id of the first one and never will be able to stop it again, basically having forgotten it when the keyup happens.

How to solve this? There are some choices:

- Have only one interval running at one time. That can easily be implemented by preceding every `timer = setInterval(…)` with `clearInterval(timer)` (nothing will happen if it was already cleared).
- Have a set of running intervals. An array, as @jarvanJiang implemented it, doesn't make much sense since you don't want to stop all intervals if only one key was released (as in `while(timers.length) clearInterval(timers.pop())`). Neither does a kind of FIFO queue where the oldest intervals are cleared.

  Instead, you want one timer id per key - a map of running intervals. When a key is released, you can determine which of the intervals you want to clear by looking it up in the map.
- Even better to implement would be only one interval, the [game loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure), and a map of boolean keys indicating which ones are currently pressed. This will allow you to manage interfering inputs, and make animations run smoother.